# Python: how to recursively apply __str__ in print

Tags: python

I had some problem printing user-defined class instance in containers. In short, if my code is:

```
class A():
    def __str__(self):
        return 'abc'

class B():
    def __str__(self):
        return str(A())

a,b=A(),B()
C=[[a],b]
print(C)
```

Then the output should be like:`[[<__main__.A object at 0x02D99910>], <__main__.B object at 0x02DD5030>]`, but I want it to recursively apply customized `__str__` and works even in nested lists or classes, i.e. I want the output to be `[['abc'],'abc']`. Any pythonic way to do?

Comment: in B, return str(A())?

Comment: The problem is that any such recursion would have to start with `list`, since ultimately *that* is what is being converted to a string with `print(C)`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not defining `__repr__` in your classes? That's what `list.__str__` will call, rather than the `__str__` methods you've defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Blckknight should have submitted as an answer, because that seems to be the correct answer (it worked for my very similar question):

**override **repr**() instead of **str**()

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "abc"
```

you can also add this for completeness
    def **str**(self):
        return self.**repr**()

@Blckknight if you want to resubmit as an answer for the points, you should.  I wish I could just add a comment but i don't have the reputation to do that.

Comment: @Blckknght, would you mind that accept this as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to override the `__str__` method of `list`, not `A` or `B`, since that's where the recursion needs to begin. That is, to turn a list into a string, you need to recursively turn each object in the list into a string. Unfortunately, you cannot do that. The best you can do is write a separate function, something like

```
def list_to_str(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        return "[%s]" % (", ".join(map(list_to_str, l)),)
    else:
        return "'%s'" % (str(l),)

print(list_to_str(C))
```

Comment: Should `print` be `def` in `print list_to_str(l):` in the first line?